# postgres authentication external

Tags: postgresql, authentication

I have to implement some safety authentication rules on postgresql DB  with a windows server. For example, rules may be "users not used for a period longer than three months will be locked" or "postgres enforces account lockout after a set number of failed login attempts."

Using authentication "standard" ( md5 on pg_hba.conf) I think is not possible.  I think that with PAM it would work. However,  PAM does not exist on windows server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Postgres has an option "valid until" that specifies user's password expiry Date&time. but, I believe, what you are asking can be done as an application feature not the Database feature.

Comment: I'm asking the database feature !! :-) I know the option but is not useful for me ( I think...) Could you explain better?Thanks Anup for your answer

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL [supports password expiry](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterrole.html) which will achieve what you want. If the user hasn't logged in 3 months, then the user could *not* have changed their password.

> Change a password expiration date, specifying that the password should expire at midday on 4th May 2015 using the time zone which is one hour ahead of UTC:
>
> ```
> ALTER ROLE chris VALID UNTIL 'May 4 12:00:00 2015 +1';
> ```

It would look something like this,

```
# CREATE ROLE foo;
# SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + '3 months'::interval;
'2017-04-30 12:53:16.344817-05'
# ALTER ROLE foo VALID UNTIL '2017-04-30 12:53:16.344817-05';
```

As far as lock-out on failed attempts, [you'll have to use PAM for that kind of thing.](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20121116004510.GD5162%40tamriel.snowman.net) Or, [SSPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Support_Provider_Interface) on Windows which should be able to do it. I don't think SSPI can do it out of the box. And, at that point you're talking about how to use a residential operating system's proprietary implementation of a spec. Good luck with that.

Other ideas are to use something like [fail2bin on Windows](https://serverfault.com/q/27757/18822). Or, [Splunk](https://www.splunk.com/en_us/solutions/solution-areas/it-operations-management/microsoft-infrastructure-monitoring/splunk-app-for-windows-infrastructure.html). Something like [pg_log_authfail](https://github.com/dalibo/pg_log_authfail) may help in this (the mentions of fail2bin and splunk come from their docs.)

On Linux you can easily do this a thousand ways. I'd look at upgrading the OS first, if possible.

Comment: Thanks Evan  Database is on server windows machine and i cant move it.Do you think is possible to use a PAM on other server? I dont think so.

Comment: @GianPiero Also don't think so.